# Removing Special Characters SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, special-characters

I have a data set example here:

| ShipName |
| --- |
| FedEx International Economy® |
| FedEx Ground® |
| FedEx® International Connect Plus |
| FedEx International Priority® |
| FEDEX® INTERNATIONAL CONNECT PLUS |
| FedEx International Priority® |
| FEDEX INTERNATIONAL PRIORITY® |

Yet, I want to remove all the special characters, so I can group them together appropriately. I realize I could just use UPPER(), however I need to remove them either way.

Because some of the characters are not on either end of the string, a simple Right() or Left() would not work.

Comment: What do you count as "special characters"? The only special character I see above is ®, and that could easily be removed with a simple `REPLACE`. `UPPER` wouldn't remove the ® character, the `UPPER` of `®` is `®`.

Comment: *I realize I could just use UPPER()* can you explain what you mean by that?

Comment: Well by using upper -some values could be grouped together, even with the registered trademark. (Which is what I am considering a special character here.

Comment: How does `UPPER` remove the ® character? Also, if you're using a case insensitive collation, which presumably you are, `'Fedex'`, `'FeDex'`, `'FEDEX'` would all be grouped togther

Comment: The Replace function worked wonderfully, Tom. I had another, and unnecessary field, in my group by clause that was preventing them from being grouped together. You are right, the case insensitive collation was not the issue. Thank you again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be as simple as using the `replace` function on your column:

```
select ShipName = replace(ShipName, '®', '')
  from Shipping
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/6f4d2/1

Further reading: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/replace-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function to remove special characters.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[funRemoveSpecialCharacters](@Input NVARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @KeepValues AS VARCHAR(50)
    SET @KeepValues = '%[^a-z0-9/ ]%'
    WHILE PATINDEX(@KeepValues, @Input) > 0
        SET @Input = STUFF(@Input, PATINDEX(@KeepValues, @Input), 1, '')
    RETURN @Input
END
```

How to use: `SELECT [dbo].[funRemoveSpecialCharacters] ('FedEx International Economy®');`

Comment: that is a bit overkill...

Comment: That'a one excellent way of completely decimating performance.

Comment: May be you guys are right(`Niels Lucas`, `Stu`). But what if the string have more then one type of special character ? Would you use replace function for all special characters ?